# Issue in radiogroup while adding radiobuttons dynamically

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

I didn't see any post similar to my problem. I have a `radiogroup` which has two buttons as follows,

```
<RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/advanced"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </RadioGroup>
```

In my application,Sometimes I need **one more button which I have added dynamically** like,

```
button=new AppCompatRadioButton(Activity.this);                                                              
button.setId(R.id.my_custom_id);                                                                                  
radiogroup.addView(button);
```

Oncheckedchangelistener code for that radiogroup,

```
(radioGroup).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    if(checkedId== R.id.basic) {
                        button.setChecked(false);
                        //my code
                    }
                    else if(checkedId== R.id.advanced) {
                        button.setChecked(false);
                        //my code
                    }
                    else {
                       //it is newly added button's part
                    }
                }
            });
```

> The problem is, when the newly added button is checked, it is not
>   unchecked when I am clicking other button. I tried to solve this in
>   `OnCheckedChangeListener` by setting `button.setChecked(false);` when
>   other buttons were checked. But it doesn't work. I don't know which makes
>   problem in that.

Can Anyone help me.Thanks!

Comment: have you set id for all views(RadioGroup&RadioButton) ?

Comment: Yeah,i did. And for that new button I used `<resources>
    <item name="my_custom_id" type="id" />
</resources>` i

Comment: Share your `OnCheckedChangeListener`..code

Comment: I have edited my question. please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Activity class context while initializing the RadioButton.

Instead of `Activity.this` use `MainActivity.this`

Here is the Full working code..in your activity:

```
        RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.group);

        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

                if (checkedId == R.id.basic) {
                    //some code
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.advanced) {
                    //some code
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.my_custom_id) {
                    //some code
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Third", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });
        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setId(R.id.my_custom_id);
        button.setText("Dynamic Button");
        group.addView(button);
        group.clearCheck();
```

In your layout Xml:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id = "@+id/group"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/basic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Basic"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/advanced"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advanced"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks ,Actually I used **AppCompactRadioButton** which was the problem in that.

Comment: oops,activity is my class. Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use AppCompatRadioButton ...also

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making radio button programmatically through java code, do this, i.e. put that radio button in xml file, but initially set android:visibility to gone, this will make sure your last radio button is not visible :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/basic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/advanced"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/new_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility:"gone"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```

and, when you need to use your radio button, then in java class, make your radio button visible again, like this:

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and then, you are good to go with setOnCheckedChangeListener :

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
            {
                    //your code
            });
```