# Dynamically added RadioButtons do not listen to onCheckChangedListener()

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, oncheckedchanged

I need to add RadioGroups and RadioButtons dynamically and generate desired view and implement onCheckChangedListener() on my dynamically created RadioGroup . The problem is, when a newly added button is checked, it is not unchecked when I am clicking other button. I have already checked this - [Issue in radiogroup while adding radiobuttons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471915/issue-in-radiogroup-while-adding-radiobuttons-dynamically) , but to no avail.

I am working in a fragment and adding views dynamically inside it. The radiobuttons do not exhibit check changed behavior. Please help me to sort this out.

```
//optionsGroup(RadioGroup),optionButton(RadioButton) 

    optionsGroup = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
    optionsGroup.setId(radioGroupCount);
    optionsGroup.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    optionsGroup.setLayoutParams(layparams);
    radioGroupList.add(optionsGroup);
    ArrayList<Options> RadioButtonOptions = question.getQuestionOptions().getOptions();
    for (int i = 0; i < RadioButtonOptions.size(); i++) {
        optionButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        optionButton.setId(i);
        optionButton.setText(RadioButtonOptions.get(i).getOptionValue());
        optionsGroup.addView(optionButton);
        optionsGroup.clearCheck();
    }
    optionsGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          for(int rb=0;rb<optionsGroup.getChildCount();rb++){
              RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) optionsGroup.getChildAt(rb);
              if(checkedId==btn.getId()){
                  radioGroupAnswerList.clear();
                  radioGroupAnswerList.add(btn.getText().toString());
                  return;
              }

          }
        }
    });
    holderlayout.addView(optionsGroup);
```

Comment: have you checked by adding that `setOnCheckedChangeListener` inside for loop?

Comment: You can check checkedId and btn.getId() is equal or not with Log.d("Compare",checkedId+btn.getId());

Comment: @TejasPandya putting listener inside the loop didn't help

Comment: i think  problem is you use clearCheck() before setOnCheckedChangeListener so use after setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: @Muhaiminurabir yes i have logged the id's....the if condition is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is you are adding view before assigning its listener . so please try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < RadioButtonOptions.size(); i++) {
        optionButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        optionButton.setId(i);
        optionButton.setText(RadioButtonOptions.get(i).getOptionValue());


    optionsGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          for(int rb=0;rb<optionsGroup.getChildCount();rb++){
              RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) optionsGroup.getChildAt(rb);
              if(checkedId==btn.getId()){
                  radioGroupAnswerList.clear();
                  radioGroupAnswerList.add(btn.getText().toString());
                  return;
              }

          }
        }
    });
 optionsGroup.addView(optionButton);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help, the other button still remains checked

Answer (score 0):

You need to uncheck other radiobutton if one radio button clicked right? and all this will be dynamically created radiobutton and radio groupe.. then you have to do this..

```
//optionsGroup(RadioGroup),optionButton(RadioButton) 

optionsGroup = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
optionsGroup.setId(radioGroupCount);
optionsGroup.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
optionsGroup.setLayoutParams(layparams);
radioGroupList.add(optionsGroup);
ArrayList<Options> RadioButtonOptions = question.getQuestionOptions().getOptions();
for (int i = 0; i < RadioButtonOptions.size(); i++) {
    optionButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    optionButton.setId(i);
    optionButton.setText(RadioButtonOptions.get(i).getOptionValue());
    optionsGroup.addView(optionButton);
    optionsGroup.clearCheck();
}
optionsGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
      for(int rb=0;rb<optionsGroup.getChildCount();rb++){
          RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) optionsGroup.getChildAt(rb);
          if(checkedId==btn.getId()){
              radioGroupAnswerList.clear();
              radioGroupAnswerList.add(btn.getText().toString());
              optionsGroup.clearCheck();
               if (isChecked) {
                 optionsGroup.check(btn.getId());
              }
              return;
          }

      }
    }
});
holderlayout.addView(optionsGroup);
```

Comment: This is not helping sir, when i change the option selection, i can't check  the previous button again

Comment: What's your Actual Requirement?

Comment: i have dynamically added radiobuttons...suppose there are two buttons A and B, now when user checks A, B should remain unchecked. after that the user can change the check from A to B or vice-versa. What i need is that the user can toggle freely and all other buttons apart from the checked one should remain unchecked.

Comment: ok you have save checked previous radio button id and set a oncliklistener in radio button. if radiobutton clicked then check saved button id is same or not. if same same then uncheck it.. please upvote my answer